# rspec stub returns nil when passed with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, stub

I'm stuck in controller testing, with a method to test which is defined in a module.

**Here is the module**

```
module CommonConcern
extend ActiveSupport::Concern
...
def fetch_suggested_portfolio(user_portfolio, amount)
PortfolioService::Suggestion
  .call(duration: user_portfolio.duration,
        risk_level: user_portfolio.risk_level,
        amount: amount,
        investment_plan: user_portfolio.investment_plan,
        portfolio_type: user_portfolio.portfolio_type)
end
```

**Here is the controller with action where the method is called**

```
  @portfolio_suggestion_object = fetch_suggested_portfolio(arg1, arg2)
```

Now when I'm checking my **stub** line using *binding.pry* it returns nil

```
wealthy.stub(:fetch_suggested_portfolio).with(@portfolios, @portfolios.amount).and_return("suggested_portfolios")
```

Also next line i.e

```
wealthy.fetch_suggested_portfolio.should be("suggested_portfolios")
```

Gives Error as below:

```
Failure/Error: wealthy.fetch_suggested_portfolio.should be("suggested_portfolios")

 ArgumentError:
   Wrong number of arguments. Expected 2, got 0.
```

Also I'm using 'rspec-rails', '3.4.2'

What's wrong with my code, any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: when you call `wealthy.fetch_suggested_portfolio` you aren't passing in arguments. The stub will only work if you match the `with` expectation. You define the method AND the stub to expect 2 arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the `fetch_suggested_portfolio` method to expect 2 arguments. Your stub only says that there is a stub of that name, that requires 2 arguments and always returns the string "suggested_portfolios". It doesn't actually supply those arguments for your call.

change:

```
wealthy.fetch_suggested_portfolio.should be("suggested_portfolios")
```

to be:

```
wealthy.fetch_suggested_portfolio(something, something_else).should be("suggested_portfolios")
```

Also, consider using the newer syntax of allows & expects. You don't have to, of course, but you might consider it as it reads better in terms of what you're actually doing when you set expectations and create mocks & stubs.

Comment: but my `and_return("suggested_portfolios")` statement is showing nil value. Why so?

Comment: do you mean it returns when you call the stubbed method? or when you literally call `.and_return(...)`?  If it's the former, I don't know off the top of my head. If it's the latter it's because the last line in the `and_return` method is actually just `nil`. You can find the source on this page: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-mocks/RSpec%2FMocks%2FMessageExpectation%3Aand_return (note that you have to find the method documentation and click 'show source'

Comment: to be clearer, when you said "Now when I'm checking my stub line using binding.pry it returns nil" the answer to that is, yes, that's the expected behavior.

Comment: but my `.and_return` is having **suggested_portfolio** so why nil is returned  ?